# Help with gmapping results using (slower) rplidar on turtlebot2

Tags: ros, navigation, rplidar, turtlebot, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I mounted my new Robopeak rplidar on the center of the turtlebot's top plate, and modified the various launch/urdf to use this scanner for gmapping.  However I have not modified any of the gmapping parameters, I'm using the same files as the turtlebot gmapping tutorials.

I can teleop around and get a map, but the walls are rather thick and fuzzy.  I suspect this is a result of the rplidar publishing at only 5 hz, not 50 hz as the original kinect.   Or possibly because the rplidar is 360 degrees and kinect was only 57 degrees?

Does anyone know why my map doesn't show a sharp defined wall?
Is the slower publishing rate responsible?
What params for gmapping should I modify to optimize for the slower rate?

I tried to add a small jpg of the map image, but not enough points.

This is on Hydro/Ubuntu 12.04, using a turtlebot2 (kobuki).

thanks
buddy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191794/help-with-gmapping-results-using-(slower)-rplidar-on-turtlebot2/) by [mrsoft99](https://answers.ros.org/users/20090/mrsoft99/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2014-09-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-03**:
At what speed you are driving robot ?

**Comment by [tanghz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21137/tanghz/) on 2014-12-18**:
Excuse me, dear mrsoft99,  I'm sorry to interrupt you. But I am facing a problem about gmapping with rplidar on turtlebot2, I am just starting to ROS, and I am struggling with this problem for a week. Could you teach me how to modify the launch/urdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you already solve the problem. If not you can find [here](http://geduino.blogspot.it/2015/04/gmapping-and-rplidar.html) how to make RPLidar works with GMapping.

---

Originally posted by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) with karma: 497 on 2015-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0